# get image blob after using sanitizer angular2

Tags: html, angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using angular2 DOM sanitizer to read an image file. I want to upload this file to the firebase storage. However, I am unable to find a way to convert the sanitized image to a blob or something that can be uploaded.

```
readImage2(inputValue: any): Observable<any> {
    var file:File = inputValue.files[0];
    return this.ng2ImgMaxService.compress([file], this.maxImageSize).mergeMap( (result) => {
      const compressedImage = window.URL.createObjectURL(result);
      const compressedImageTrusted=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(compressedImage);
      return Observable.create((observer) => {
          observer.next({imageUrl: compressedImageTrusted});
      })
  })
}
```

In this code, I want to upload the `compressedImageTrusted` file to firebase storage. This file has a type `SafeUrlImpl`which I'm not sure how to convert to something that I can upload to a firebase storage. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know Firebase nor angular at all, but if `inputValue` is an `HTMLInput[type="file"]` then you already have your Blob, namely `file`. Isn't it what you want to send ? [_Edit_] or maybe it's `result` if you want to send the compressed image, `compressedImage` variable is just a string (a BlobURI). What you pass to `URL.createObjectURL` has to be a Blob (or a MediaStream but it's probably not here)